# Building Python extension for Saxon/C fails: "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Tags: python, xml, anaconda, saxon-c

**Summary:** Setup fails, saxon-c on Python Conda Windows

Results from: saxon-setup.py build_ext -if (see source listing below)

```
running build_ext
building 'saxonc' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I'm inexperienced with compilers/compilation ( .pyx .cpp .c .dll etc.) and how to go from python scrip to compiled code. Looks like Saxon is sourced in Java, crossed to C source, then compiled locally on Windows, then hooks are added so you can get at that compliled C code from your python scrip -- yikes, my head is spinning!)

**Environment:** Windows 10, miniconda, Python 3.9.2

Following is a "breadcrumb" list of the attempted install with some links:

```
saxon-c (Home Edition / open-source, easy to install)  
https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml  
libsaxon-HEC-win-setup-v1.2.1.exe  
path to setup.py: c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon   
Docs:  
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!starting/installingpython  
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html
```

```
cython installed via conda (easy)  
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cython  
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  
cython                    0.29.22          py39hd77b12b_0
```

```
setuptools installed via conda (easy)  
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/setuptools  
setuptools                52.0.0           py39haa95532_0
```

```
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers (required some navigation to avoid the IDE / large download)  
Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019.   
C++ build tools  
latest versions of MSVCv142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools and   
Windows 10 SDK    
are checked.
```

```
https://pythonwheels.com/ (brief look - no easy solution)  
https://packaging.python.org/ (brief look - many options, no easy solutions)  
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (brief look - no Saxon)  
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-scientific-packages/#the-conda-cross-platform-package-manager  
(I wish Saxon was a "scientific" package with a simple conda install.)
```

**saxon-setup.py listing - results in error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
    
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(    #Long line reformatted here for readability. see original
[Extension("saxonc", 
["saxonc.pyx", 
"../SaxonProcessor.cpp", 
"../SaxonCGlue.c", 
"../SaxonCXPath.c", 
"../XdmValue.cpp", 
"../XdmItem.cpp", 
"../XdmNode.cpp", 
"../XdmAtomicValue.cpp", 
"../XsltProcessor.cpp",
"../Xslt30Processor.cpp", 
"../XQueryProcessor.cpp",
"../XPathProcessor.cpp",
"../SchemaValidator.cpp"], language="c++",
)]),include_dirs = ['../jni', "../jni/unix"],
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}
)
```

**Next attempts (after comment)**
in Anaconda Promp (miniconda3) - trying to relate Anaconda to Powershell

```
conda update conda
activate xml   #my xml conda environment
conda init
```

I close and reopen that Anaconda Prompt (showing results of the prior init, below)

```
(xml) C:\Users\rick>conda init
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\activate
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Scripts\deactivate
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
no change     C:\Users\rick\miniconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
no change     C:\Users\rick\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
no change     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
No action taken.
```

I run Powershell as administrator

```
PS C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon> py --version
py : The term 'py' is not recognized ...

PS C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon> python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

```
PS C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon> python saxon-setup.py build_ext -if
running build_ext
building 'saxonc' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Not sure if this of any help

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current>csc /version
3.9.0-6.21160.10 (59eedc33)
```

**Third attempt (after comments)**
Got it compiled - see answer.

Comment: Hi, are you using powershell to build the Saxon/C python extension on windows? Please see guide here: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!starting/installingpython

Comment: ond1 - thanks for the link, tried to follow - see above, next attempts.

Comment: There are lots of articles online about the missing vcvarsall.bat. I wonder you need to install the VS visual C++ compiler?

Comment: If you managed to solve “Unable to find vcvarsall.bat”, post an answer that explains how you did it. If there are additional issues, post a new question.

Comment: ond1 - thanks for the tip. You nailed it. mzjn - posted answer per your request.

Answer (score 2):

Fully installing the Windows C++ compiler solves *"error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".*

If you just install Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019, and check off: C++ build tools, latest versions of MSVCv142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools and Windows 10 SDK, you will miss some required components.

The solution was to go back to the Build Tools installer and also install the entire "C++ Build Tools" set of components. If you missed this, just run Microsoft Build Tools again (its just an installer program) then modify your install, to select C++ Build Tools from the main page:

[image]

This will select a bunch of components for you and the install will be large (many gigs), but it will then compile for Python.

After that install, the standard Windows installed program list expanded to include:

1. Windows SDK
2. Windows SDK AddOn
3. Microfsoft Web Deploy 4.0
4. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office
5. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86)
6. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)

To compile in a anaconda environment:

open a Anaconda Powershell Prompt as administrator

```
PS cd C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda activate xml #xml here is my conda environment to sandbox the new software and try it out
PS C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon> get-executionpolicy
Bypass  
#sometimes Powershell has permission restrictions on scripts running just checking here
$Env:PYTHONPATH += ";C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHEC1.2.1\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon"  #PYTHONPATH env variable was blank ahead of this

python saxon-setup.py build_ext -if
```

Takes a while to complile

readme.txt says to install the documenation but that wasn't found:

```
(xml) C:\Users\rick>pydoc -w saxonc
No Python documentation found for 'saxonc'.
```